# Skype chat history and web browsing history CHECK

Tags: webserver, skype

In an office work place, can a network admin have access to my Skype chat history and web browsing history without logging in to my pc since all pc's are connected with the same network?

i am wondering weather is it secure to keep my login details saved in a office computer?

Can our skype chats be read in real-time without any body noticing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat history and contacts are saved in a windows directory : C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Skype\ .
Network admin has access to those files and can access them. 
So basically, Yes. Network admin can view your chat history or even export them without you noticing.

Comment: And as an extension - in a typical office environment, you need to be aware that the company's admin team could (in most jurisdictions) access anything and everything you do or have done on that machine.